# why does @Html.ValidationSummary("...") output a div with style=display:none instead of outputting nothing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Assuming there are no Validation errors, the resultant html will be injected from a call to `@Html.ValidationSummary`

```
<div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><span>...</span>

<ul><li style="display:none"></li>

</ul></div>
```

and assuming you have the standard `validation-summary-valid` in your css (display: none;) the div will not be shown.

*Thats fine* but wouldnt everything work the same if `@Html.ValidationSummary("...")` output nothing instead of a 'hidden' div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the unobtrusive jquery functions are going to populate the validation summary client side, would the scripts not need a place to put the summary?  Otherwise, you would have to reload the page each time and that defeats the purpose of client-side validation.

Comment: <ul><li style="display:none"></li> This is causing csp (content security policy) error in my browser console! can anyone help me how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's so that client-side validation can show the div if validation fails on the client later on.